# React bootstrap how can I force my button to be thinnier?

Tags: reactjs, button, react-bootstrap

I have an issue with my buttons using React-bootstrap, I can't find how to make them thinnier : (I'd like the check to be on the same height as the "Validate"  )
[image]

Here is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import { Check } from 'react-bootstrap-icons';

<div className="container">
   <div className="row">
      <Table striped bordered hover>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>PyFeel</th>
               <th>Google CNL</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <Button variant="success" onClick={() =>
                     { this.validatePred(k) }}>Validate 
                     <Check/>
                  </Button>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <Button variant="success" onClick={() =>
                     { this.validatePred2(k) }}>Validate 
                     <Check/>
                  </Button>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </Table>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried to add `size='sm'` but the issue is the same

Comment: can you post a sandbox? here it is displayed at same line. https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-swanson-rl1vz?

Comment: @Apostolos it seems like on Sandbox there isn't the same margin as on React https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-hooks-m49bg?file=/index.js

Comment: so maybe you are using somewhere else another css file?

Comment: @Apostolos no I don't have any special CSS, I guess it's react that put some margin around the container I'll look further

Answer (score 0):

You are best to make your own button and then add a max-height. The css for that button looks pretty simple.